# Question on function multiplication of str and int and type errors in python

Tags: python, typeerror

Hi so I am pretty new to python and programing in general and I can not seem to figure this problem out I just keep on getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'" for a function I am writing.
Here is my function or at least the basics of it.

```
def y(x):
  return print("lorem") * x

y(100)
```

Any help I would be very grateful for because this is the first time i have asked a question on here.

Comment: print("lorem" * x) will work

Comment: What do you expect this to do?  You called a function that returns `None`, and then tried to multiply that `None` by 100.  Whatever you expected for output, please follow the examples in your tutorial materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're looking for, but try the following:

```
def y(x):
    print("lorem" * x)
    return

y(100)
```

If you're instead looking to print each "lorem" on separate lines, try the following:

```
def y(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print("lorem")
    return

y(100)
```

Comment: Thank you so much i have been doing tutorials recently I just wanted to go without them for a week or two as to not just mindlessly follow their logic. Also if you know what are some useful resources for python for a beginner like me

Comment: @Ark04 No worries! I find W3Schools has good programming resources. Try checking them out.

Comment: ok I think I have, but I did not pay much attention at the time, but I will check there again. Thank you